# Spring MVC Portlet Eclipse plugin

Tags: spring-mvc, eclipse-plugin, portlet

I am stuck with it. please anyone know about simple portal/portlet plugin for eclipse. please let me know with detail description. because i want to make portlet by using Spring MVC. I DON'T WANT TO USE LIFERAY!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to install Spring Source Tool Suite.
It is just another eclipse but with all the Spring framework related plugins preloaded in it.

I think it would be easier for you to create spring portlet using it.

Hope this helps you.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look in the book "Portlets in Action", Ashish Sarin.

You will get everything you need to know about portlets and Spring MVC. Personally, it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want use spring mvc into liferay portlets yo should:

1. Create a maven portlet with liferay archetype.
2. in the pom.xml add all libraries for spring, portlet and liferay.
3. config your portlet creating, web.xml, applicationContext.xml, and portlet.xml
4. Write your code.